# MS Teams. How to add a file into the file tab of the bot programatically?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

In teams, there is an bot app called Dev3.
Our users can take a chat with the bot Dev3.

When user want to upload a file. She/He can upload an attachment file with the attachment clip icon.

Meanwhile after uploading the attachment files, She/He can review the file uploaded in the file tab.

For Users, it is a quick way for users to check the files between She/He and the bot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now we have following demand.

We get the graph api privilege at our server side and we want to upload some file to the file tab too! where user can also check the file which is uploaded by application.

We want to confirm that whether it is possible or not?

Currently, we tried the way of uploading file into the **user's private one drive folder** *but those files are not displayed in the file tab.*

[image]

Can anyone give some suggestion on how to putting a file in the file tab?

Answer (score 1):

The Files tab in channel is nothing it linked to SharePoint site default folder, Please take a look at [Upload Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) This API restricted to file size to 4MB. if you want to upload greater than 4MB you need to upload the file in stream or chunks.